# In Java, how can I get a variable to print two doubles separately instead of adding them?

Tags: java, variables, double

I have to create a method (outputDegreesF) that prints the information below (a temperature conversion) and only accepts a single parameter. How can I get my variable **degreesC** to print degreesC and fahrenheit separately instead of just adding them?  Like "0.0 32.0". I can't change anything to a string or Java freaks out.

```
public class tempChart {

        public static void degreeHeader (String cTitle, String fTitle) {
      System.out.println(cTitle + fTitle);
      }

        public static void outputDegreesF (double degreesC) {
         double fahrenheit = 32.0 + (degreesC * 9.0 / 5.0);
         degreesC = degreesC + fahrenheit;
         System.out.print(degreesC);
        }

      public static void main(String[] args) {
       degreeHeader("Degrees (C)", " Degrees (F)\n");
       System.out.println();
       outputDegreesF(0.0);
       outputDegreesF(5.0);
       outputDegreesF(10.0);
       outputDegreesF(15.0);
       outputDegreesF(20.0);
       outputDegreesF(25.0);
       outputDegreesF(30.0);
       outputDegreesF(35.0);
     }



    }
```

Comment: `degreesC = degreesC + " " + fahrenheit`...?

Comment: No, you can't insert a string into a double. But thank you!

Comment: `String text = NumberFormat.getInstance().format(degreesC) + " " + NumberFormat.getInstance().format(fahrenheit)` or `String text = degreesC + " " + fahrenheit`

Comment: In order to print both values next to one another you need to convert them to a string. This can be done several ways. The first way I would recommend is to call String.valueOf(fahrenheit) and set a new string equal to this value. Then do the same for degreesC. Then add the two new strings into the print statement. You can also directly call String.valueOf() inside the print statement. This will remove the need for two extra variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to print the number as a string.
replace `outputDegreesF()` with

```
public static void outputDegreesF(double degreesC) {
    double fahrenheit = 32.0 + (degreesC * 9.0 / 5.0);

    System.out.print(degreesC + " " + fahrenheit); // Easier
    // Or
    System.out.printf("%.7f %.7f", degreesC, fahrenheit); // Used more and lets you format
}
```

If you want to change the amount of decimal places printf prints, change the `7` to the amount you want.

PS:
You don't need the `System.out.println();` line since in the previous line you already add a new line (the `\n` in the string)

Comment: Boy, that makes me feel incredibly stupid, but thank you.

Comment: I was thinking I couldn't add anything to what it was printing because of the single parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could I suppose create a nested Degrees Class and let that class do the conversions from Celsius to Fahrenheit (or Fahrenheit to Celsius) for you. Here is a runnable example that converts an array of Celsius values to Fahrenheit:

```
package tempchart;

public class TempChart {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The temperatures in Celsius you want to convert
        // to Fahrenheit and table within a 1D double type 
        // array.
        double[] degreesCelsius = 
                {0.0, 5.0, 10.0, 15.0, 20.0, 25.0, 30.0, 35.0};

        // Declare the Degrees class.
        Degrees deg = new Degrees();
        // Table Header
        System.out.printf("%s | %8s%n", "Celcius", "Fahrenheit");
        System.out.println("========+===========");

        // Generate the table based on the temperatures 
        // held within the degreesCelsius array...
        for (int i = 0; i < degreesCelsius.length; i++) {
            deg.setCelsius(degreesCelsius[i]);
            System.out.printf("%-7.2f | %5.2f%n", deg.celsius, deg.fahrenheit);
        }
    }

    // Static Nested Class - Degrees
    static class Degrees {
        public double celsius;
        public double fahrenheit;

        // Getters And Setters
        public double getCelsius() {
            return celsius;
        }

        public void setCelsius(double celsius) {
            this.celsius = celsius;
            //Convert to Fahrenheit - Multiply by 9, then divide by 5, then add 32
            this.fahrenheit = (((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32);
        }

        public double getFahrenheit() {
            return fahrenheit;
        }

        public void setFahrenheit(double fahrenheit) {
            this.fahrenheit = fahrenheit;
            //Convert to Celcius - Deduct 32, then multiply by 5, then divide by 9
            this.celsius = (((fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5) / 9);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also apply other temperature scales to the above nested class.